# Running a Pagodo.py Google Dork search results in an error: pagodo.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 50 -e 35.0 -j 1.1

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using Pagodo.py as part of the OSINT framework to scrape a webpage, following this [hakin9.org guide](https://hakin9.org/pagodo-passive-google-dork-automate-google-hacking-database-scraping-and-searching/).

I ran the command they give as an example and I also played around as advised there with the arguments passed to the script, nonetheless, I could not make it work for me, it throws the following error:

```
usage: pagodo.py [-h] -g GOOGLE_DORKS_FILE [-d DOMAIN] [-i MINIMUM_DELAY_BETWEEN_DORK_SEARCHES_IN_SECONDS] [-x MAXIMUM_DELAY_BETWEEN_DORK_SEARCHES_IN_SECONDS] [-l] [-m MAX_SEARCH_RESULT_URLS_TO_RETURN_PER_DORK] [-p PROXIES]
                 [-o [JSON_FILE]] [-s [URL_FILE]] [-v VERBOSITY]
pagodo.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 50 -e 35.0 -j 1.1
```

- Have you ever come across this error while using Pagodo?
- What are the arguments you use to make it work for you?
- What do you personally do, in order to properly run a Pagodo.py search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-e` and `-j` are `proxychains4`'s arguments, not `pagodo`s. If you run it like:

```
proxychains4 python3 pagodo.py -g GOOGLE_DORKS_FILE -s -e 35.0 -j 1.1
```

it should work.

Without `proxychains4` it should just be:

```
python3 pagodo.py -g GOOGLE_DORKS_FILE -s
```